# Set axis limits when plotting 2 vertical axes in MATLAB via plotyy

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the following data sets to plot:

```
data1 = [ 3 6 99 4 5];
data2 = [ 0.2 1.5 1.75 1.0 1.2];
```

What's peculiar about my situation is that I need data point `data1(3)`, which is equal to `99`, *not* show up on the graph. I'm using 99 as a way of pushing observations outside the desired axis limits so that there are no visible observations for certain values of the independent variable.  (I'm plotting the data points with markers only, no lines.)

While `data1` and `data2` have totally unrelated scales and meanings, they share the exact same dependent variable:

```
X=40:1:44
```

I'm plotting with the following commands, which I derived from the [MATLAB plotyy documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html):

```
[AX,H1,H2] = plotyy(X,data1,X,data2);

set(get(AX(1),'Ylabel'),'String','This is vertical axis 1') 
set(get(AX(2),'Ylabel'),'String','This is vertical axis 2')     

set(H1,'LineStyle','none','Marker','*');
set(H2,'LineStyle','none','Marker','s');
```

So far, so good.  What I cannot figure out is how to enforce the correct limits on both of the vertical axes.  My desired limits are:

```
ylimits1=[0 3]
ylimits2=[0 10]
```

**How can I set limits for each vertical axis?**

---

I have tried this

```
set(get(AX(1),'Ylim'),ylimits1) 
set(get(AX(2),'Ylim'),ylimits2)
```

and

```
foo = gca
set(foo(1),'ylim',ylimits1);
set(foo(2),'ylim',ylimits2);
```

but neither work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following should work:

```
[AX,H1,H2] = plotyy(X,data1,X,data2);

set(AX(1),'ylim',ylimits1);
set(AX(2),'ylim',ylimits2);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Could you explain why it makes sense to do `set(get(AX(1),'Ylabel'),'String','This is vertical axis 1')` to set the label property, but you only need to do `set(AX(1),'ylim',ylimits1)` to set the ylim property?  That is, why do the `get(AX(1),...)` part of the statement?

Comment: Then at least I'm not crazy to be confused!  I understand your solution though, which is all that matters, since it works.  Thanks again.

Comment: actually I can't tell you, why you're first attempt isn't working. But the second is definitely wrong, as `gca` is the wrong handle in this case.

Answer (score 0):

some other random things you can do

```
x1 = 1:10
y1 = x1.^2
x2 = 10:120
y2 = sin(x2)
[AX,~,~] = plotyy(x1,y1,x2,y2);
set(get(AX(1),'Xlabel'),'String','both plots')
set(get(AX(2),'Ylabel'),'String','plot 2') 
set(AX(1),'YLim',[1  25],'YTick',7:23)
```